# Is there any way to make printf/sprintf handle combining characters correctly?

Tags: perl, unicode, printf

Combining characters appear to count as whole characters in `printf` and `sprintf`'s calculations:

```
[    é]
[   é]
```

The text above was created by the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

for my $s ("\x{e9}", "e\x{301}") {
        printf "[%5s]\n", $s; 
}
```

I expected the code to print:

```
[    é]
[    é]
```

I don't see any discussion of Unicode, let alone combining characters, in the function descriptions.  Are `printf` and `sprintf` useless in the face of Unicode?  Is this just a bug in Perl 5.20.1 that could be fixed? Is there a replacement someone has written?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the answer is to use [`Unicode::GCString`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::GCString)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Unicode::GCString;

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

for my $s ("\x{e9}", "e\x{301}", "e\x{301}\x{302}") {
        printf "[%s]\n", pad($s, 5);
}

sub pad {
        my ($s, $length) = @_;
        my $gcs = Unicode::GCString->new($s);
        return((" " x ($length - $gcs->columns)) . $s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably be aware of the [Perl Unicode Cookbook](http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-standard-preamble.html).  In particular [℞ #34](http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/05/perlunicook-unicode-column-width-for-printing.html), which deals with this very issue.  As a bonus, Perl v5.20.2 has it available as `perldoc unicook`.

In any case:  The code included in that article is as follows:

```
use Unicode::GCString;
use Unicode::Normalize;

my @words = qw/crème brûlée/;
@words    = map { NFC($_), NFD($_) } @words;

for my $str (@words) {
    my $gcs  = Unicode::GCString->new($str);
    my $cols = $gcs->columns;
    my $pad  = " " x (10 - $cols);
    say str, $pad, " |";
}
```